# mysql number of people assigned to a task

Tags: mysql, database

I have the following tables...

Tasks
[alt text http://img260.imageshack.us/img260/3695/screenshotbg.png](http://img260.imageshack.us/img260/3695/screenshotbg.png)

People
[alt text http://img685.imageshack.us/img685/6445/screenshot1f.png](http://img685.imageshack.us/img685/6445/screenshot1f.png)

tasks_people
[alt text http://img260.imageshack.us/img260/1061/screenshot2r.png](http://img260.imageshack.us/img260/1061/screenshot2r.png)

... and I want to get a list of tasks, with a count of people assigned to them. Note that a person can be assigned to a task more than once (on different dates). For some reason I dont seem to be able to manage it.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: regarding your note saying that "a person can be assigned to a task more than once" shall these all be counted as 1 or as many?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want same person's many assignment to be counted as 1 do:

```
select tasks.task_id, tasks.title, count(distinct tasks_people.people_id) 
as p_counter
from tasks left join tasks_people
on tasks.task_id = tasks_people.task_id
group by tasks.task_id
```

Otherwise simply `count()` it

```
select tasks.task_id, tasks.title, count(tasks_people.people_id) as p_counter
from tasks left join tasks_people
on tasks.task_id = tasks_people.task_id
group by tasks.task_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant see your table structure, but you can try selecting the distinct values from tasks_people (distinct taskid, personid) and then count and group by.

Answer (score 0):

```
select task_id, count(distinct people_id) as people_assigned_to_task
from tasks_people
group by task_id
```

and if count + distinct misbehaves (i.e. takes too long), you can try this:

```
select task_id, 
(select count(*) from 
      (
          select distinct people_id from tasks_people i 
          where i.task_id = o.task_id
      ) 
) as people_assigned_to_task
from tasks_people o
group by task_id
```